# If else condition based sql query

Tags: mysql

| Country | ID | Period | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| America | null | 20 | expired |
| null | 1234 | 30 | expired |
| null | null | 40 | expired |

Suppose i have a table with this data,

1. if country is existing eg: America then i fetch associated period i.e 20 from db.
2. Else i need to check whether particular id is existing then taken 30.
3. If both are not existing we take the default both null column that is 3rd row which is 40.

So the precedence of fetching period is Country>ID>Default.

select period from table where type = 'expired and ((cntry_nam = 'America' and  id is null) or (cntry_nam  is null and  id = '1234')) and cntry_nam is not null and serv_id is null

Instead of making 3 db calls one for checking if country is present else second db call if id is present then fetch that period. third if both are not present the default in which both cases are null. How can we optimise it into a single db call. I have tried using **case** statement too it didnot work.

```
SELECT
(case            
when cntry_nam = 'America' and id is null                
THEN rr.prd_mnth            
else                
(case                     
when cntry_nam is null and id = '1234'                         
THEN rr.prd_mnth                     
else                         
(case                              
when cntry_nam is null and id is null THEN rr.prd_mnth                             
end)                    
end)    
end)
FROM table rr where type = 'expired'
```

Comment: What is your expected results for the sample data?

Comment: Suppose if america is found then we should not be checking other cases and return the period of america. so its 20. Else if america is not there if id 1234 is present then 30 is returned. else default both null case whihc is 40 to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the nested cases because the cases are tested in order, so that implements the priority you want.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN country IS NOT NULL THEN period
    WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 30
    ELSE 40
END AS Period
FROM yourTable
WHERE type = 'expired'
```

Comment: Here it is not checking for the particular Country/Id, and also we get two records here. But flow should be stopped when this is encountered, Suppose if america is found then we should not be checking other cases and return the period of america. so its 20. Else if america is not there if id 1234 is present then 30 is returned. else default both null case whihc is 40 to be returned.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought America was just an example of a non-null country, not a specific country to check for.

Comment: Can you add other countries to your sample data, and show what the desired result should be?